# Creating 4 digit number with no repeating elements in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, random

Thanks to @RedBassett for this Ressource (Kotlin problem solving): https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/koans.html

I'm aware this question exists here:

[Creating a 4 digit Random Number using java with no repetition in digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317298/creating-a-4-digit-random-number-using-java-with-no-repetition-in-digits)

but I'm new to Kotlin and would like to explore the direct Kotlin features.
So as the title suggests, I'm trying to find a Kotlin specific way to nicely solve generate a 4 digit number (after that it's easy to make it adaptable for length x) without repeating digits.

This is my current working solution and would like to make it more Kotlin. Would be very grateful for some input.

```
fun createFourDigitNumber(): Int {
  var fourDigitNumber  = ""
  val rangeList = {(0..9).random()}

  while(fourDigitNumber.length < 4)
  {
   val num = rangeList().toString()
    if (!fourDigitNumber.contains(num)) fourDigitNumber +=num
  }

  return fourDigitNumber.toInt()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the range you define (`0..9`) is actually already a sequence of numbers. Instead of iterating and repeatedly generating a new random, you can just use a subset of that sequence. In fact, [this is the accepted answer's solution to the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18317374/817496). Here are some pointers if you want to implement it yourself to get the practice:

- The first `for` loop in that solution is unnecessary in Kotlin because of the range. `0..9` does the same thing, you're on the right track there.
- In Kotlin you can call `.shuffled()` directly on the range without needing to call `Collections.shuffle()` with an argument like they do.
- You can avoid another loop if you create a string from the whole range and then return a substring.

If you want to look at my solution (with input from others in the comments), it is in a spoiler here:

> fun getUniqueNumber(length: Int) = (0..9).shuffled().take(length).joinToString('')

(Note that this doesn't gracefully handle a length above 10, but that's up to you to figure out how to implement. It is up to you to use `subList()` and then `toString()`, or `toString()` and then `substring()`, the output should be the same.)

Comment: Wow thank you so much! That is a lot of great input!

Comment: If you really want to get into Kotlin features, you might also check out the [Kotlin Koans](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/koans.html), which are a set of practice problems that will introduce you to a bunch of language features and paradigms!

Comment: Oh what a great ressource! Thanks for posting! Will definitely share this in my class. They even have a Edu Plugin for Intellij!!

Comment: I've found the plugin to be a tad buggy (some links in the descriptions don't work right) and they refer you back to your previous solution sometimes, which you can't see easily in the IDE, but it is how I went through the problem set personally. It's a great integration regardless of a few rough edges…

Comment: Good to know. Then I'll probably stick to the online version - that looks pretty neat anyways!

Comment: That's pretty much the solution I came up with, but I'd suggest a couple of tweaks.  First, use `take(n)` instead of `subList(0, n)`; does the same, but shorter and clearer.  And second, the `toString()` doesn't quite do what we want; it returns e.g. `[2, 5, 4, 7]`.  So use `joinToString("")`, which returns e.g. `2547`.  Also, as a matter of style, you could make it clearer you're dealing with characters by using an explicit character range: `('0'..'9')`.

Comment: Aaah thank you so much for the "joinToString("")"! That saved me following line:

var randomNumber =""
(0..9).shuffled().take(4).forEach {randomNumber +=it }

I didn't know how else to do it, but joinToString("") really made it nicer.

Thanks to you both, nice to have such a good community to ask :)